# Create kind of temporary workbook from active workbook and then save temp. wb without changes in act. wb.. Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I have a workbook from which I need 2 sheets. The sheet 1 is needed to be copy pasted as values (to eliminate formulas and preserving formatting). MY logic is following :1) create a kind of temporary workbook of the initial file 2) then do copy paste as values 3)select only sheet 1 and 2 4) save this temporary workbook (with two sheets) to the folder. This is done in order to avoid any changes in the active (original ) workbook. I am using the following code and it seems to work. However my initial active workbook  is also changed (in the first sheet only values (no formulas)). What should I change in my code , so that my schema starts working.

```
Set tb = ActiveWorkbook    
tb.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy    
tb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues        
tb.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select    
tb.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Copy         
tb.SaveAs Filename:="C:path"
```

Comment: Move the copy/paste values step to *after* you create the temporary workbook.

Comment: ^ and call it on the temporary workbook, not your original one.

Comment: If you're not changing the original workbook at all, then where is this code running from? Another, 3rd workbook?

Comment: Thank you for advises,  I solved it by 1) creating a duplicate sheet 1, 2) then copy paste in the duplicate  3) save 2 sheets to another file 4) delete duplicated sheet from the original file